# Umnraco URL's also display pages with Views name other then Created Nodes

Tags: url-routing, umbraco7

I am working on Umbraco v7, I have just noticed the Umbraco also returns pages with matching views name, it should only display pages with created nodes Url, for example if a view name contactus and a node name contact-us, Umbraco shows both pages, How I can force Umbraco not to display pages with views name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely dealing with the 404handlers.config. Remove

```
<notFound assembly="umbraco" type="SearchForTemplate"/>
```

from the list.

If a page is not found, Umbraco will go down this list before returning a 404.